# index.php redirection for five website in a one webhosting

Tags: php, redirect, web, header, web-hosting

I have 5 domains for my 5 websites and I have only one host so I hosted my 5 websites in that host (e.g. site1's URL is 192.168.xx.xx/site1/index.php,
 site2's URL is 192.168.xx.xx/site2/index.php).  I need make my index.php (192.168.xx.xx/index.php) automatically redirect the website using user's requests. I tried this code but it is not correct please help me.

```
<?php
 $host=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
 header("'Location:http://exampledomain.com/' . "$host"");?>
```

Comment: You should put these types of redirects in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is concatenation. In PHP the `.` indicates concatenation. You are using `.` but you have additional quotes around your variables that are unnecessary.

So your code:

```
 header("'Location:http://exampledomain.com/' . "$host"");?>
```

Should be:

```
 header("Location:http://exampledomain.com/" . $host);?>
```

There is also an example on the [`header`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) command reference that may be very helpful to you:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is invalid.

This is valid:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
header("Location:http://exampledomain.com/{$host}");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation is invalid:

```
header("'Location:http://exampledomain.com/' . "$host"");?>
```

It should be:

```
header("Location:http://exampledomain.com/" . $host);?>
exit;
```

Also, remember to add `exit;` after `header()` to stop the PHP execution, else it will continue executing.